# How do I get Weka 3.6 and 3.7 to accept "-S" filter option for Stop word removal in Snowball stemmer from command line?

Tags: weka

I have tried both Weka 3.6 and 3.7 but neither will accept the following command:

java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -N 0 -L –S -stemmer "weka.core.stemmers.SnowballStemmer" -M 5 -tokenizer "weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -delimiters \W -min 1 -max 1" -i "inputfile.arff" -o "outputfile.arff"

The error message that is returned is
"
Illegal options: ?S
Filter options: -C -R -V -P -W ... -S ....
"

i.e. a list of valid filter options of which "-S" for stopword removal is listed as the means of implementing stop word removal.

I have already checked online weka documentation at
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html

which also specifies "-S" as a valid filter switch.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is something about your dash in the S parameter that looks a bit bigger than the others.

I did a copy and paste of this character and it also appears larger than the minus key.  Perhaps try '-' instead.

My optometrist claims that I have 20/20 vision.  Hopefully it has assisted in some way for the problem mentioned above.

Hope this helps!